# Particular case of ini file : new elements in QMap and Enum from another file

Tags: c++, qt, ini, qmap, qsettings

I' was seen other solutions here, but those solution suggest to modify the file containing the main enum and QMap of a ini file.

So, here the problem : I'm working in QT (C++) about a software's plugin because I **must not** change anything on the software's code.

on the software's files, there are, for ini file, an *enum* and a *QMap* on a file called *ini.h* and *ini.cpp*

on **non-modifiable** ini.h (I modified as cards for clarity):

```
class CORE_LIBRARY_API Config : public QObject
{ 
  Q_OBJECT

  enum Key 
  {
  // General
  Version,
  // Cards
  King,
  Queen,
  Jack
  }
 ...
```

on **non-modifiable** ini.cpp :

```
inline const QMap<Config::Key, QString> sKey 
{
  // General
  { Config::Version,            "Version"                   },
  // Cards
  { Config::King,               "Cards/King"                },
  { Config::Queen,              "Cards/Queen"               },
  { Config::Jack,               "Cards/Jack"                }
}
...
```

I want to add from another files the Knight and the Joker on modifiable plugin from ini file :
What I do actually, **of course, that don't work, the plugin don't read Joker or Knight's value actually...**

on **modifiable** ftarot.h :

```
class FTarot : public Plugin
{ 
  Q_OBJECT
  enum Key 
  {
  // TarotCards
  Joker,
  Knight
  }
 ...
```

on **modifiable** ftarot.cpp :

```
inline const QMap<FTarot::Key, QString> sKey 
{
  // TarotCards
  { FTarot::Joker,               "TarotCards/Joker"            },
  { FTarot::Knight,              "TarotCards/Knight"           }
}
...
```

of course, I can modifie the .ini file so here it is:

```
[General]
Version=x.x.x
[Cards]
King=3
Queen=3
Jack=1
[TarotCards]
Joker=8
Knight=2
```

So... is there are a problem about what I do here ? Or I must take a deeper look on the Initialization where there are the QSetting part ?

(The **non-modifiable** QSetting on ini.cpp ):

```
bool Config::init()
{
   ... *(verification part, not important here)*

   QSettings config(sConfigFilePath, QSettings::IniFormat);

   QMetaEnum metaEnum = QMetaEnum::fromType<Key>();

   ... *(verification part, not important here)*
   }
  }
  return *(verificaion ok/nok)*;
}

// This one use the sKey list to take a value "card" from the list cardfound used in case the card wasn't found:
QVariant Config::variant(const Key& card, const QVariant& cardfound)
{
  QSettings config(sConfigFilePath, QSettings::IniFormat);
  return config.value(sKey.value(card), cardfound);
}
```

Thank you for reading !

Comment: You should show the bit of code that actually *uses* `sKeyMap`, as well as what you hope to accomplish with the new keys. If you are not allowed to change `Config::init` I would say you are dead in the water.

Comment: Ok, I edit that immediately about sKeyMap ... but look like I'm dead in the water :/
Maybe that's possible to create a second ini file ? Or is that possible to overwrite the "old" enum/QMap with the Plugin code ?

Comment: Impossible to say from this side of the computer screen.

Comment: I changed sKeyMap to sKey for clarity too.
Anyway, look like I must make another solution unless someone get one here... I get the idea to create a second ini file if possible... I'll see that ^^